# With Android you can transfer data to any site's form and trigger the send button

Tags: android

hello any site you want to log in form with an Android app in the background. How I can do this process, but I did not find a result if you can help me, thank you in advance.

more examples
Any educational institution has a student add form. I want to send my student information from my own database to this form

Comment: Hi there, Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please see [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). We request you to show your effort first, what you have done and tried so far. We can not answer direct question where there are no efforts. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 0):

You can create AsyncTask class to submit the form data to the URL either using POST or GET.

for example:
`

```
class NetworkActivity extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>{
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String.. params)
{
 try{
  Url url = new URL("Your URL Here");
  HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
  connection.requestMethod("POST");
  connection.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
  connection.setDoOutput(true);
  OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
  os.write("Form data here"+params[0]); // write form data here e.g. studentname=XYZ&rollno=123
  InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
  BuffredReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
  //Fetch the output into a String
  StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
  while((line=br.readLine())!=null)
   {
     output.append(line);
   }
  return output.toString();
  }
 catch(Exception e)
 { 
  e.printStackTrace();
  return null;
 }
}

protected OnPostExecute(String result)
{
   //Process the output here.
}

}
```

`
Now create a new object of this class and call the execute function the initiate the Network activity.

`new NetworkActivity().execute("form data");`